# Google Analytics - JDBC or ODBC driver

Tags: jdbc, google-analytics, odbc

Is there a JDBC or ODBC driver that connects directly to Google Analytics?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.  Google's API doesn't use SQL.  Try this:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/tutorials/hello-analytics-api

Answer (score 0):

[RSSBus](http://www.rssbus.com/jdbc/) has a bunch of JDBC drivers and one is for Google Analytics. No experience with it; I'd love to hear some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

RSSBus have a Beta release of ODBC driver. It worked fine from Excel, but does not allow you to create a Linked Server. For that, they suggest their SSIS component.